# redux-saga: How to create multiple calls/side-effects programmatically for yield?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-saga

With redux-saga, one can execute multiple effects in parallel:

```
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

// correct, effects will get executed in parallel
const [users, repos]  = yield [
  call(fetch, '/users'),
  call(fetch, '/repos')
]
```

How can i create those "call"-calls **programmatically**?

What i want to achieve is this:

Lets say i have an array with different parameters and i want to execute a request to a server per parameter, but in parallel with redux-saga:

```
const parameters = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

const allMyFetchCalls  = parameters.map( (p) => makeCallRequestWithParameter(p) );
```

makeCallRequestWithParameter would create a function call (or in redux-saga-speech: an effect) *call(fetch, param)* like in *yield call(fetch, param)*

```
const resultArray = yield allMyFetchCalls;
```

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please note that `call` effect doesn't call anything at the time.
It just creates Plain JavaScript Object and returns. So what you want is not so difficult.

```
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

const params = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
const responses  = yield params.map(p => call(fetch, p))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!

Comment: will it be concurrent or not?

Comment: it's concurrent.

Answer (score 11):

So according to the [redux saga docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RunningTasksInParallel.html) as of 11/17/2019 its says in order to make it execute in parallel you need to use all()

```
yield all( arrayOfSomething.map( eachSomething => call( myFunction, eachSomething ) ) )
```

or if you want to compute some stuff before making your call

```
yield all( arrayOfSomething.map( eachSomething => {
   // do some computations

   // important you return the function which is automatically done 
   // for you in the one line map, this has gotten me a few 
   // times when I am just coding fast
   return call( myFunction, eachSomething ) )
} )
```

Answer (score 7):

This might work aswell https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#alleffects

```
function* mySaga() {
  const { customers, products } = yield all({
    customers: call(fetchCustomers),
    products: call(fetchProducts)
  })
}
```

Comment: works when all requests are successful but throws error even if a single call is failed. I want to get the response of all requests even if some fails. how to do it?

Comment: @VikasBansal Bit late to the party. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398163/getting-results-from-redux-saga-all-even-if-there-are-failures)