# how to fetch end point with different parameters in redux saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

So i had end point function

```
import AppConfig from "../config/app-config";

const create = (baseURL = AppConfig.apiUrl) => {
  const api = apisauce.create({
    baseURL,
    headers: {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    },
    timeout: 10000
  });

const listAssignedDevices = vehicleId =>
    api.get(`api/fleet/vehicle/${vehicleId}/devices`) 

return listAssignedDevices
export default create
```

*edited*

i try to call that end point with array as a list of parameter in redux-saga

i already try using map function like in [redux-saga: How to create multiple calls/side-effects programmatically for yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043644/redux-saga-how-to-create-multiple-calls-side-effects-programmatically-for-yield)

```
const listVehicleId = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

const response = yield listVehicleId.map(vehicleId => call(api.listAssignedDevices, vehicleId)
console.log(response)

if (response.ok && response.headers['content-type'].indexOf('json') !== -1) {
    console.tron.log('AturBcak - OK')
    yield put(AturBcakActions.aturBcakMultipleSuccess(response.data))
  }
```

but the response is undefine, i want to know how to do multiple call with different parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question by doing yield all

```
const response = yield all(
    listVehicleId.map(vehicleId => 
      call(api.listAssignedDevices, vehicleId)  
    )
  )
```

from this

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1800#issuecomment-468627409

Answer (score 0):

`api.listAssignedDevices` has to be a function that takes `vehicleId` as parameter, performs network request and returns the result. From your example it is just a function that constructs a url from  vehicleId but doesn't perform network request

```
const listAssignedDevices = vehicleId => fetch(`vehicle/${vehicleId}/devices`)
```

Comment: im sorry i didnt make it clear, that end point is just example. i already make a get method in my api.js file so that api.listAssignedDevices is making network request. my bad, but thank you for your answer