# Nested .map using redux-sagas call

Tags: reactjs, concurrency, promise, nested, redux-saga

I need to make a series of api calls, defined by 2 parameters.  Let's call them `users` and `foods`.  Each is an array of strings.  For each user, and for each food, I need to construct a unique api call, which calls a route.  I have a utility saga to do this:

```js
function* getUserFoodDetails(requestParams) {
  const { user, food } = requestParams
  const response = yield call(
    axios.get,
    `api/foodstats/${user}/${food}`,
    {
      params: {
        startDate: 'some datestring',
        endDate: 'some datestring'
      }
    }
  );
  return response;
}
```

(Yes, I know this API design is not great, but its what I have to work with.) This saga can call one route at a time.  I read [redux-saga: How to create multiple calls/side-effects programmatically for yield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043644/redux-saga-how-to-create-multiple-calls-side-effects-programmatically-for-yield/40044111), and I had once asked my own question [Getting results from redux-saga all, even if there are failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398163/getting-results-from-redux-saga-all-even-if-there-are-failures) for how to implement error handling in this type of scenario.  The general consensus was to use the utility saga with `yield all` to call many routes at once.  If there was only one parameter, we could do this

```js
const responses  = yield users.map(user => call(getUserDetails, { user }));
```

And we would end up with an array of user data mapped from the original users array.

***Now*** I am in a situation where I have a 2-dimensional dataset, and I need to make a call for every combination of `user` and `food`.  For example,

```js
const users = ['me', 'you', 'someone'];
const foods = ['bananas', 'oranges', 'apples'];
```

I am working within an existing app and I need to conform to the end-result data structure.  The structure the rest of the UI expects is an array of arrays of result data.  The first level array corresponds to each user, and the next level corresponds to each user's food data.  (While I may want to change this, there's only so much legacy code refactoring I want to deal with at once).  The structure should end up like this:

```
[
  [ // 'me' data:
    { noEaten: 44, enjoyment: 5 }, // 'me' 'bananas' data
    { noEaten: 14, enjoyment: 2 }, // 'me' 'oranges' data
    { noEaten: 22, enjoyment: 4 }, // 'me' 'apples' data
  ],
  [ // 'you' data:
    { noEaten: 12, enjoyment: 2 }, // 'you' 'bananas' data
    { noEaten: 334, enjoyment: 12 }, // 'you' 'apples' data
  ],
  [ // 'someone' data
    { noEaten: 14, enjoyment: 2 }, // 'someone' 'oranges' data
    { noEaten: 22, enjoyment: 4 }, // 'someone' 'apples' data
  ]
]
```

Its not a very semantic structure, but its what I'm trying to get to.

The previous code achieves this with a nested map call within promises

```js
const allUsers = user.map(user =>
  const all = foods.map(food => 
    fetch(`api/foodstats/${user}/${food}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
  )
  return Promise.allSettled(all)
)

Promise.all(allUsers).then(res => doSomethingWithData(res));
```

This nesting of Promise.all and allSettled is very strange to me, but it does result in the above data structure.

I need to recreate this with sagas.  Within my saga, I try to do a nested map as well:

```js
    const data = yield all(
        users.map(user =>
            foods.map(food =>
                call(getUserFoodDetails, {
                    user,
                    food
                })
            )
        )
    );
```

However this does't work. I have 2 layers deep of `.map`, but only 1 layer deep of `all` and `call`.  what I end up with an array of redux saga objects:

[image]

While I understand why this is happenining, I'm not sure how to fix it.

How can I nest `.map` statements with redux sagas, such that the api calls are made, and the data is returned in the same nested structure with which I made the calls?  Is this possible?  Is it worth bothering?  Or is it better to come up with some intermediate data structures to obtain a single-layer array, and then restructure back to the 2-layer array that's needed in the components?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was right in front of me - I'll leave it here in case anyone ever needs something similar.  If a single call to `yield all(users.map(() => {))` gives a 1-layer array of data, then I needed a 2-layer call to `yield all` to get a 2 layer array of data.  Its a little convoluted, but 2 utiliy sagas, each which takes a single parameter:

```
// Utility saga to call route once, for 1 user's single food
function* getFoodDetails(requestParams) {
  const { user, food, params } = requestParams;
  const response = yield call(
    axios.get,
    `api/foodstats/${user}/${food}`,
    { ...params }
  );
  return response;
}

// Utility saga to call route for every food for a single user
function* getUserDetails(requestParams) {
  const { user, foods, params } = requestParams;
  yield all(foods.map(food => 
    call(getFoodDetails, { user, food, params })
  ))
  return response;
}

// Saga to call route for every user
function* getAllUserFoodData(requestParams) {
  const { users, foods, params } = requestParams;
  const response = yield call(
    yield all(users.map(user => 
      call(getUserDetails, { user, foods, params })
    ))
  );
  return response;
}
```

So `getAllUserFoodData` maps over all users, creating the first level of the array, which is one item per user.  In each of those map calls, `getUserDetails` maps over each food for a given user, creating the second level of the array, which is one item per food.  Finally `getFoodDetails` is called, which calls the route for a single user's single food.